# Find closest preceding row in a DataFrame from a given timestamp in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find a way to return the nearest **preceding** row in a dataframe that meets two criteria:

1. The row must be the first timestamp (in time - therefore chronological) prior to the given timestamp
2. The row must also be one's whose `Type` column == 'Quote'

I want to then create two columns df['is_ask_trade'] and df['is_bid_trade']. For every record in the `type` column marked 'Trade' I would like to find its matching quote, based on its price in the `price` column. The Quote has to precede this trade in time too i.e. it cannot happen at the same time as the trade.

If the trade row's `price` <= `bid_price` then '1' else 0 and the vice versa if the price <= `ask_price`.

The index is sorted (DateTime), however, it contains duplicate values; some pertain to a quote, others to a trade. The information needs to be retained.

The data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'datetime': [
      '2020-11-16 01:39:06.22021017', '2020-11-16 01:39:06.22021020', '2020-11-16 01:39:06.22021022',
      '2020-11-16 01:39:06.22021031', '2020-11-16 01:39:06.22021033', '2020-11-16 01:39:06.22021036'],
  'type': ['Quote', 'Trade', 'Trade', 'Quote', 'Quote', 'Trade'],
  'price': ['NaN', 7026.5, 7026.5, np.NaN, np.NaN, 7024.0], 
  'ask_price': [7026.5, 7026.5, 7026.0, 7026.5, 7026.0, 7026.5], 
  'bid_price': [7024.0, 7024.5, 7024.5, 7024.0, 7024.5, 7024.5]})
```

I was kindly helped to by SO to develop a similar solution, however, I am unable to adapt it to this new challenge.

I have tried using: `df.index.get_loc[index_of_trade_row, method="ffill"]` and filtering for the nearest 'Quote' rows, however I receive an error owing to the non-unique index.

**Expected Output:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'datetime': [
      '2020-11-16 01:39:06.22021017', '2020-11-16 01:39:06.22021020', '2020-11-16 01:39:06.22021022',
      '2020-11-16 01:39:06.22021032', '2020-11-16 01:39:06.22021033', '2020-11-16 01:39:06.22021033'],
  'type': ['Quote', 'Trade', 'Trade', 'Quote', 'Quote', 'Trade'],
  'price': ['NaN', 7026.5, 7026.5, 'NaN', 'NaN', 7024.0], 
  'ask_price': [7026.5, 7026.5, 7026.0, 7026.5, 7026.0, 7026.5], 
  'bid_price': [7024.0, 7024.5, 7024.5, 7024.0, 7024.0, 7024.5],
  'is_bid_trade': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
  'is_ask_trade': [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]})
```

For example, the final `is_bid_trade` matched the `bid_price` in the quote row -2 rows prior, as the  Trade logically occurred after the quote in time.

All help gratefully received, thank you.

Comment: This might work: `df.iloc[df[df.datetime < '2020-11-16 01:39:06.22021032'].index[-1]]`

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't get the question wrong, you want to get the row with 'Quote' type and the nearest preceding 'datetime'. So hope this helps.

```py
df.iloc[df[(df.datetime < index_of_trade_row) & (df.type == 'Quote')].index[-1]]
```

Comment: Thank you but it's more complicated than that - I will edit the OP to make it clearer.

Comment: You are welcome, if a simpler solution comes up, I'll certainly edit